# Problems with Transparency in Android

Tags: android, performance, drawing, transparency

I have stumbled across a problem on some of the Android Tablets notably Samsung Galaxy Note, Galaxy Tab 10 and Nexus 10. The problem is after I keep the application running for a while and resume it from recents or via a Notification, the application UI messes up transparency of the icons and control widgets.

For instance, there is a Linear Layout that has a grey gradient background and two imagebuttons drawn on top of it. These imageButtons have transparent background and an icon set as source.  When the problem manifests itself, it is observed that UI is drawn  something like this: 
[image]

The Grey background gradient also loses its alpha and is drawn flat when this happens.

Has anyone observed similar behavior before?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to disable hardware acceleration on the activity containing these views, or disable it on the LinearLayout container.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void disableHardwareAcceleration(View v) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
      }
}
```

If you have a private variable that references the LinearLayout, pass it to this method to disable hardware acceleration.

Comment: Is this a known problem in Android devices with Hardware acceleration turned on? Also, is this issue documented somewhere?